# uint8_t to two's complement function

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode4.3, twos-complement

I'm using objective-c in xcode. How can I convert a uint8_t piece of data into a decimal two's complement? The range is -127 to 127, correct?

If I have:

```
uint8_t test = 0xF2
```

Is there a function or method built in that I can use? Does someone have a simple function?

Thanks!

Comment: You can just cast to signed, (int8_t)test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
int8_t twosComplement = (int8_t)test;
```

Answer (score 1):

The question seems a bit confused.  It asks to convert to decimal 2's complement, but 2's complement is meaningful **only** in binary, not in decimal.

If you want to make a unit9_t value into a signed value, you can
- cast it to some signed type like so: (int16_t)unsigned8variable
- assign it to a variable that has a signed type

However, beware of overflow.  Your uint8_t value can be anything from 0 to 255.  If you assign to an 8-bit signed type, there are representations for values from -128 to +127, and any original value greater than 127 will suddenly appear to be negative.  Choose a type that's big enough to hold any value you might actually see.  int16_t would be safe because it goes up to 32767.